# Nexus3 Conan login ERROR: Wrong user or password.

Tags: nexus, conan

Setup Nexus3 Conan plugin based on https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-conan/blob/master/docs/CONAN_USER_DOCUMENTATION.md, but can't seem to push a package to it.

When I try to login I get:

```
$ conan user redacted -p redacted -r conan-hosted
ERROR: Wrong user or password. [Remote: conan-hosted]
```

My remote config looks something like:

```
{
   "url": "https://example.com/repository/conan-hosted/",
   "verify_ssl": true,
   "name": "conan-hosted"
}
```

I'm able to login to nexus console using that userid and password.
I just can't seem to login with it via conan.

Comment: Turns out this might be an issue with conan client on Ubuntu 16.04.  I opened a ticket on this https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/4190

Comment: JFrog is able to upload from Ubuntu 16.04, so it might be an issue with Nexus Conan Plugin itself https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-conan/issues/39

Comment: Please make sure you've got *Conan Bearer* active in *Administration -> Security -> Realms*

Answer (score 0):

The problem was environment related on my side. This is now fixed for me.

Comment: I have the same issue but I don't understand your fix